# CALC "Variable" is undefined

Tags: bash, calc

I am trying to do:

```
FIELD1b=0.37920; FIELD1a=0.28069; calc '(FIELD1b-FIELD1a)**2'
```

But, what I get is:

```
"FIELD1b" is undefined

Error in commands
```

Comment: What is `calc`?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/calc.1.html

Comment: You didn't set a variable in calc. What did you expect?

Comment: how is the way to set a varibale?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/calc.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calc` doesn't seem to understand shell/environment variables. You can instead pipe your expression to `calc`, like:

```
FIELD1b=0.37920; FIELD1a=0.28069; echo "($FIELD1b-$FIELD1a)**2"  | calc -p
```